# Contractibility of the quotient of an analytification of a smooth variety by a finite group (if the field is trivially valued)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry, non-archimedean-fields, analytic-geometry, berkovich-geometry

Let $k$ be a field and $X$ be a smooth irreducible $k$-variety with an action of a finite group $G$. I consider $k$ as a trivially valued field.

It is known from results of Berkovich ("[Smooth p-adic analytic spaces are locally contractible](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002220050323)"), Thuillier ("[Géométrie toroïdale et géométrie analytique non archimédienne. Application au type d'homotopie de certains schémas formels](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00229-007-0094-2)"), and others that the analytification $X^\text{an}$ is contractible, one constructs a retraction $H:X^\text{an}\times I\to X^\text{an}$ to the skeleton of $\mathfrak X$ denoted by $S(\mathfrak X)$. If $k$ is trivially valued then this skeleton is just a point, so $X^\text{an}$ is contractible.

I see several times that $X^\text{an}/G$ is also contractible, for example, slide 28 of "[Toroidal deformations and the homotopy type of Berkovich spaces](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/%7Ethuillier/articles/Toric_Leuven.pdf)" by Thuillier states this. Hovewer, I could not find a proof of this result. It's clear that this should follows from the fact that the homotopy could be chosen $G$-equivariant. Berkovich in the proof of Cor. 8.5 in the above paper writes that this is just "by construction", but this is not obvious for me. Does anyone know where I can find  the clear argument? Or maybe any other suggestions?

P.S. I see that Hrushovski and Loeser have a similar construction for $\widehat{X}$ and they actually check that one could choose a $G$-equivariant retraction. Then they constructed a continuous map $\pi_x:\widehat{X}(k^\text{max})\to X^\text{an}$ where $k^\text{max}$ is a maximal complete field containing $k$, with value group $\mathbb{R}$ and its residue field equals to algebraic closure of residue field of $k$. This $\pi_x$ is surjective and a homeomorphism in case $k=k^\text{max}$. In 14.2 of "[Non-archimedean tame topology and stably dominated types](https://doi.org/10.1515/9781400881222)" they get some results for $X^\text{an}$ from results for $\widehat{X}$ but I do not see any $G$-equivariant result for $X^\text{an}$. Could one use their results to see $X^\text{an}/G$ is contractible or it is easier to use the direct approach of Berkovich and Thuillier?

Comment: Basically I can assume that the singular locus of $X/G$ is smooth, i.e $X/G$ has isolated singularities. But I guess that the fact is true without this assumption.

Comment: Perhaps you can find the answer to your question in Section 3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.2216.pdf? E.g., Corollary 3.6 of that work seems very relevant.

Comment: Title of the paper [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444730/contractibility-of-the-quotient-of-an-analytification-of-a-smooth-variety-by-a-f#comment1148390_444730) by @JacksonMorrow:  [Ulirsch - Tropicalization is a non-Archimedean analytic stack quotient](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.2216).

Comment: Dear @JacksonMorrow, thank you for the paper but I think that Cor. 3.6 states something else. Roughly speaking, it says that the functor of taking the underlying topological spaces of the analytification commutes with a finite group quoitent.  This does not help with contractibility.